# How can I use data that isn't displayed in a row in React-Table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table, react-usememo

For example, I would like to use `id` as something that would be passed in the Actions header located in the Actions Component via row.values. While I can get the values for first and last name, I cannot for id

```
const Accounts = () => {

    const [columns,setColumns] = useState(useMemo(() => [
                {
                    Header: 'First Name',
                    accessor: 'firstName',
                },
                {
                    Header: 'Last Name',
                    accessor: 'lastName',
                },
                {
                    Header: 'Actions',
                    Cell: ({row}) => (
                        <Actions values={row.values}/>
                    )
                }
            ],
            []
        ));
        const [data,setData] = useState(useMemo(() => [
            {
                id:1,
                firstName:"john",
                lastName:"johnson",
            },
            {
                id:2,
                firstName:"dave",
                lastName:"jones",
            },
            {
                id:3,
                firstName:"steve",
                lastName:"smith",
            },
        ], []));


return (

        <>
            // react-table component
            <Table columns={columns} data={rdata}/>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access all your row data using row.original